# Does "refrain" mean the same as "intentionally refrain"?

Tags: meaning

Some verbs seem to have as part of their meaning that they are intentional, such as refrain, refuse, etc. So, when we want to say that the act in question is intentional, do we need to add the adverb "intentionally"?

> He refrained from informing her that he is bankrupt.

Does that mean the same as:

> He intentionally refrained from informing her that he is bankrupt.

Comment: What does a dictionary tell you about this?

Comment: The dictionary tells *me* that ***refrain*** means [*Stop **oneself** from doing something*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/refrain). I can't really see how one could do something like that without volition. But over 28,000 hits in Google Books for [*deliberately refused*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22deliberately+refused%22) (another inherently "volitional" verb) make it pretty obvious there's nothing remotely unusual about including such adverbs to add *emphasis*.

Comment: It implies intention but does not demand it.

Comment: If I believed someone owed me the bit that he is bankrupt, and he kept it to himself, oh, yes, would I say his refrain was intentional. I would then think even less of him if he claimed he had only 'refrained from informing' me. If he thought that allowed for a naive omission, I would have no respect for him. But that's just me.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Where did "owed me the bit" come from?  I understand it but have never heard it before.

Comment: Intentional or deliberate can be more than emphasis. A refusal could be summary, knee-jerk, emotionally charged (e.g., enraged), and so on. These are not necessarily compatible with intention or deliberation. An *intentional* or *deliberate* refusal can be a refusal that was to some extent thought through first, or chosen with a cool head.

Answer (score 0):

According to the *New Oxford American Dictionary*, Refrain is defined as:

> stop oneself from doing something

Note the "oneself". This means that the verb is always reflexive, implying intent.